# displaying google maps API v2 on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

Iam trying to display google maps for specific location on android app

but thoese red line errors said:Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
CameraUpdate cannot be resolved to a type

GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type

GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a variable

LatLng cannot be resolved to a type

MapFragment cannot be resolved to a type

MarkerOptions cannot be resolved to a type

R cannot be resolved to a variable

The import com.google.android.gms.maps cannot be resolved

The method getFragmentMnager() is undefined for the type

although  i make my project reference to google play service library
and instaalgoogle play service on SDK

the MainActivity.jave:

```
            package com.example.test;


              import android.app.Activity;
              import android.os.Bundle;
              import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
              import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
              import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
              import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
              import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private final LatLng location_boudl  = new LatLng(24.767300, 46.664289);

      private GoogleMap map;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


          map = ((MapFragment)   getFragmentMnager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


        map.addMarker(new   MarkerOptions().position(location_boudl).title("here"));

       map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    CameraUpdate update =          CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location_boudl,15);


   }

    }
```

- activity_main.xml:

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

          <fragment
             android:id="@+id/map"
             android:layout_margin="25dp"
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="0.78" />

         </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- manifest.xml:

  ```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.example.test"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <permission 
        android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

         <uses-permission  android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

     <!--tells the android that we will use google maps in our app -->
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```

  ```
      <uses-feature
          android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
          android:required="true"/>



        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         </activity>

               <meta-data
                 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                  android:value="AIzaSyDdbDcuf78QpeSYULuvZrCwbtK_G4f4dQc" />

                <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 

     </application>

     </manifest>
  ```

any help please , really appreciate

Comment: Have you imported google play services library in your project?

Comment: i am imported the google play serices library in my project in the first place , but thosse errors  are apear and red line below each error in java code

Comment: You may try to use `Android Studio` due to eclipse Android development has been deprecated. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE&index=25&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSPjWpLPFEfOCbezi6vATIh) is step by step to implement that.